How do I connect ScottPlot from code behind to xaml in WPF?
I am trying to create a Bar Plot in WPF xaml, I want bars in differenct categories, like it's documented here: ScottPlot Cookbook
I also used this for knowing how it works with WPF: ScottPlot WPF Quickstart
I got this code now:
public Statistieken()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Loaded += (s, e) =>
    {
        double[] xs1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        double[] ys1 = { 5, 10, 7, 13 };
        BarPlot bars1 = WpfPlot.Plot.AddBar(ys1, xs1);
        bars1.Label = "Alpha";

        double[] xs2 = { 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        double[] ys2 = { 7, 12, 9, 15 };
        BarPlot bars2 = WpfPlot.Plot.AddBar(ys2, xs2);
        bars2.Label = "Beta";

        WpfPlot.Plot.Legend(location: Alignment.UpperLeft);
        WpfPlot.Refresh();
    };
}

I just cannot get it to work, this line always gives an error: BarPlot bars1 = WpfPlot.Plot.AddBar(ys1, xs1);
I tried lots of things using ChatGPT too, also exactly what is documented in the Documentation, I can create it all in the xaml.cs, but then adding it to the xaml is the problem.

What's the error?

'Plot' does not contain a definition for 'AddBar' and no accessible extension method 'AddBar' accepting a first argument of type 'Plot' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Well, you have the docs - why do you not read it? Your code is different than the code from the docs

Why do you expect there to be an AddBar method? Are you confusing types e.g. used the wrong namespsce import?
